# Spring Boot DatasourceBean error, Macbook, MySQL

Tags: mysql, spring, macos, jdbc, spring-boot

I'm getting the following error when I deploy my application to Tomcat 8. I have MySQL installed on my macbook :

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.catalina.productcarried.dao.impl.ProductCarriedDAOImpl.jdbcTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private javax.sql.DataSource org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration$JdbcTemplateConfiguration.dataSource; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
```

Here is my application.properties file :

```
#Database properties local
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/simulator?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false    
spring.datasource.username=root 
spring.datasource.password=       
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
debug=true
```

Comment: Could you paste your pom content ?

Comment: Is the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` on classpath?

Answer (score 2):

> Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).

Your `application.properties` is not taken into account for some reason. Note that the `driver-class`is unnecessary, Spring Boot detects that from the `url` parameter.

Make sure to review the following:

1. The mysql driver is defined in your dependencies
2. The content of the `application.properties` file you provided in description is in [one of the supported locations](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)